# Captured image is rotated 90 degress

Tags: android

I've written an app to capture an image. The problem is that the image is rotated 90 degrees after the capture. I've setted the

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(NINTY_DEGREES);
```

But this only affects the previewing of the `SurfaceView`. The real problem is that the bytes I get from the camera is flipped. Why does this happend? Is there a setting I can set to flip it before capture?

I my activity subcribes to an event, when the image is captured. This is how I register when the `byte[]` is filled:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (null != callback)
                    callback.onJpegPictureTaken(data, camera);
            }
        });
```

In my `Activity`

```
public class History extends BaseWindow implements OnClickListener, CaptureImageCallback
```

and the relevant method:

```
@Override
public void onJpegPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ImageEditing.class);
        i.putExtra("image", data);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

You can see the parameter `data` which contains the image data, this byte array is rotated 90 degress. I could of course rotate the `ImageView` 90 degress, but since I will work with other systems, such as a homemade webservice, I would need to apply this hot fix to every external system. How can I correct this rotation?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe something to do with ExifInterface

Comment: HI. DId you managed to solve this ?Manu thanks.

Comment: @Paul Sort of. Quite a hack thou, but it seems to work. I've added a rotatation matrix to the image and rotated it 90 degress, and saved it as a new bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "Angle" of your captured image and rotate as per angle.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

int angle = 0;

if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
    angle = 90;
} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
    angle = 180;
} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
    angle = 270;
}

Log.d("Tag", "Angle: " + angle);

Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(angle);

if (angle != 0)
    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Comment: This would not affect the `byte[]` array, I guess? The problem is that the byte array is flipped

Comment: But try this, you have your image path, passed that and set somewhere in image view and see the outcome my friend. I used when I get 90 degree rotated image and need to set on screen with portrait mode.

Comment: I'll give it a try. But I doesn't have any imagepath, just a byte array containing the imagedata. The real problem is that I need to change the order of the bytes in the image.

Answer (score -1):

As name indicates `setDisplayOrientation()` is for **display** only. [Doc says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29):

> This does not affect the order of byte array passed in
>   onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos

So if you want to save rotated image, you need to rotate it yourself prior saving.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote. I rephrese myself: `I've setted the
camera.setDisplayOrientation(NINTY_DEGREES);
But this only affects the previewing of the SurfaceView`

Comment: yes. because this is what it does. you expect saved image to be rotated but I am telling that if you want to rotate on save you have to rotate yourself